# 2013 Nested Dialog Fields - another way to reference in jquery other than "select[title=xyz]"

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog

I am trying to use JQuery to create parent/child relationships and set a field in the child (lookup of parent) to that of the child. I am using Content Editors in the forms (these are just the main parts of the scripts, assume the getParameterByName function operates fine and all  tags and ref's are correct):

Parent Form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var raidID = getParameterByName("ID");

    $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']").each(function(index ) {
         onClick = $(this).attr('onclick');
         newOnClick = onClick.replace("?","?raidID=" + raidID + "&");
         $(this).attr('onClick', newOnClick);
    });

});
```

Child Form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var raidID = getParameterByName("raidID");

    if(raidID != "") {
       $("select[title='RAIDRef']").val(raidID);
       $("select[title='RAIDRef']").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

});
```

Now, this works for the Calendar form when I create a new child but with a custom list the child doesn't populate the ID field...

I traced this back to the fact that the Child Modal seems to null the "title" parameter of the select box and all you get is ID, ORIGINALID etc - so I tried referencing the select box by ID or ORIGINAL ID:

```
$("select[id='ctl00_ctl41_g_268da7b1_0182_46f5_ae78_041563a06a9e_FormControl0_V1_I1_D15']").val(raidID);
```

and

```
$("select[originalid='V1_I1_D15']").val(raidID);
```

but this hasn't worked - is there another way to send a parent ID to a child modal dialog form or another way to reference a field that doesn't have a TITLE parameter set? Or am I missing something/doing something completely wrong?

Thanks,

Alec

Comment: It would appear, after further investigation that the <select> options are not populated until mouse-over... so, my belief is that jquery can't then select a .val() as there is nothing to select...

Any pointers on how I can force mouse-over/population of the select field?

Answer (score 0):

For selecting id you should use

```
$('#ctl00_ctl41_g_268da7b1_0182_46f5_ae78_041563a06a9e_FormControl0_V1_I1_D15').val(....);
```

Comment: Thanks Amal, I will amend my code to use, but I've discovered another issued, stated as a comment to the original post. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: I think you should set the `val` after the population of the `select` items. How are you populating the `select` items?

Comment: I am not populating them, they are populated from the list field choice values. However, when inspecting the `select` field, it appears to have no options until you mouse-over it, at which point the field is populated.

Are you suggesting that I should populated 1 value into the `select` field of the one I want to use? And then `select` it using `.val`? What is the best way of populating 1 value in to a `select` field?